# Django e banco de dados Oracle (acessando suas views via ORM)

Tags: oracle, django, orm, django-queryset

Olá, apesar do titulo auto explicativo. Detalharei minha duvida a seguir.

Possuo uma base de dados Oracle pré existente, integrei-a com o django configurando a conexão default no settings e rodando o comando manage.py inspectdb > _models.py. Criando assim um arquivo com diversas classes mapeadas de minha base de dados.

Minha duvida é: Tal base possui views, rotinas sql predefinidas que me retornam uma seleção de dados bastante útil. Gostaria de saber como utiliza-las dentro do django, pois elas não são mapeadas nativamente e minha leiga compreensão de banco de dados e orm me deixam sem muitas escolhas a não ser tentar reescrever suas logicas em sql puro.

Perdão se a resposta for simples e obrigado pelo amparo antecipadamente.

Comment: Vi aqui algo sobre a classe `Meta` : https://blog.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/ ; espero que seja útil =]

Comment: Caso tenha problemas com inglês, fala que eu tento traduzir os pontos relevantes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gostaria de agradecer abertamente ao Jefferson Quesado por compartilhar um link com a lógica ideal, tendo eu apenas tido que adaptar ao meu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Realmente, `DataBase Views` são tabelas comuns do banco de dados, com seus valores gerados dinamicamente durante sua consulta, funcionam como `select` ambulantes e não ocupam espaço no banco de dados, apesar de serem persistentes. Meu baixo entendimento disto prejudicou na busca criativa de uma solução.

O detalhe realmente veio do fato de serem persistentes, são consideradas então tabelas reais da base de dados e por tanto, **também podem ser mapeadas.**

Criei uma classe no meu _models.py com o exato nome da minha View do banco de dados Oracle em questão, seguindo o escopo padrão de uma classe que representa um objeto relacional. Herdei-a de `models.Model`, adicionei seus atributos com os exatos nomes e propriedades dos campos da view que pretendia mapear (caso tiver dúvidas sobre quais propriedades atribuir, dê uma espiadinha no SQL da sua tabela e veja as propriedades dos campos que ela referencia, inclusive um detalhe importantíssimo, as primary/foreign keys para o modelo de sua view são na verdade as keys das tabelas que sua view abstrai, mesmo que pareça desnecessário, gostaria de deixar este detalhe com seu devido destaque aqui, já que no escopo da view não há quaisquer referências a chaves primarias/secundárias, mas não se engane e atribua `primary_key=True` aos devidos campos. Caso contrário o django levantará uma exceção de ID desconhecido ao fazer qualquer `QuerySet` e então nada feito. Haha).

Finalmente, a classe `Meta` **dentro** da classe do modelo da sua data base view. Referenciando sua view como uma tabela real (afinal ela nas entranhas é).

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'nome_da_sua_view'
```

No mais, recomendo a visita ao [link](https://blog.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/) deixado pelo Jefferson Quesado, vale a pena conferir.